# No comment option?

Tags: support, comments

A few minutes ago I visited this question on the main site:

[How to design index for faster deletes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45712/how-to-design-index-for-faster-deletes/45715#45715)

Link as it appears in my browser (IE8). I could not for the life of me see a comment option to ask a query so, for my sins, I posted it as an Answer. @gbn was kind enough to upvote it whilst I was browsing the site in a further tab in IE and I clicked the link to read his comment. So now I have the question opened up a 2nd time as:

[How to design index for faster deletes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45712/how-to-design-index-for-faster-deletes/45715?noredirect=1#comment80952_45715)

But this time I can see the "add comment" link under the question plain as day. Can someone explain this behavior to me please?

OS is Windows XP (yes and IE8, it's a corporate PC)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't intending this to be a self answer, but it is. Upon posting I noticed I had a further notification for a Badge at 50 reputation allowing me to comment everywhere.

Does feel a bit of a flawed situation when people like me get into a position of needing to ask for more background information but can't comment to a question. Oh well.

Comment: Some (people without enough rep to comment) write it as answer, like you did. It usually ends with a flag and the answer converted to comment.

Comment: Point of clarity: You can certainly comment on your own question, you just can't comment on someone else's question.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. Until you have 50 reputation, you can only comment on your own posts. Seems backward to me, where you can post an answer with 1 rep but have to wait for 50 to comment. Not like it's all that hard to reach 50 anyway.

This has been discussed on meta quite a bit, and it seems this is the way it will stay, based on the most prolific post that I could find:

[50 reputation for making comments is too high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53647/50-reputation-for-making-comments-is-too-high)